# My Itunes and AppStore are in German, and I can switch them to english

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, ipad

Every thing else seems fine in english.  just bought the thing today. My head's about to pop off my neck.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Are the menu buttons and navigation in German, or is it just the country for purchases?

Comment: What iTunes are you talking about? "iTunes" on your iPad or iTunes on your Mac?

Answer (score 2):

First check Region of your Apple ID:
Open *iTunes* and click on *iTunes Store*. In the store, click on *Anmelden* on the top right and enter your password. Under *Apple ID Übersicht* select *Land oder Region ändern*. Choose the appropriate one.

Then check your system locale. You can find it under *Systemeinstellungen* (*System Preferences*)->*Sprache & Text* (*Language & Text*)->*Sprache* (*Language*). Drag *English* to the top of the list. This will change your system language to English.

If you don't want to, you could use *[Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/)* to permanently or temporary to change the language *iTunes* starts up in. **This does not affect the stores!**

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, on the right hand side you will see a flag. This flag represents the region you are in (of the store) Click this and you are able to reselect your region.

Answer (score 0):

To change it temporarily you can scroll down and on the right you'll find a flag, click on it and choose a different region; then you'll be logged out.

To change the language permanently you need to go on your Account (from Spotlight, for example) and then change the Region. It will also ask to change the payment method if your credit card is a German one, you'll need to insert a british credit card or an American one. After you switch the region, btw, your list of purchased applications will be cleared, since applications - for apple - are region dependent. I think it's a stupid and terrible bug, since if you move to another country and you return your credit card you'd lose also the applications, but for Apple it is a feature since they keep this stuff like this since ages. But you can get the purchased applications back, switching back to German. But this is still unpractical since the AppStore also helps keeping apps up to date.
The fact I own a German credit card doesn't imply that my primary language is German, but the geniuses at Apple think it is... 
What can I say, AppStore, AppleId, and iTunes are the dumbest stuff I ever seen; I suppose Apple wants to excel also in being dull. I hate all this (once I lost all of my iTune music after an iOS upgrade); every time I think to install ubuntu on my macbook.